# Auto-generated proxy class doesn't match service contract

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy-classes

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to auto generate a proxy class to a WCF service.  In the service contract, one of the methods, `GetActiveSessions()`, is defined as returning a `Dictionary<Guid, Session>`, but here's how the property appears in my proxy class:

```
public MyNamespace.ArrayOfKeyValueOfguidSessionxjDRWaWoKeyValueOfguidSessionxjDRWaWo[] GetActiveSessions() {
    ....
}
```

There's also another instance of this strange behavior where a service method that is supposed to return a `Guid` is defined as returning a `string` in my proxy class.  While the methods seems to work as specified when I used the methods as defined by the proxy class, I'd like to not have to work with objects of type `ArrayOfKeyValueOfguidSessionxjDRWaWoKeyValueOfguidSessionxjDRWaWo` in my code.

Any ideas as to what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The proxy serialized wire format will match the schems defined in the WSDL/XSD. However there are many anonymous types and arrays in the WSDL which have no name and when you work with a proxy you need to name them. So WCF calculates a unique name by chaining names across the element path. If you want a different name then either create a wrapper on top of the proxy (and maintain it) or don't use anonymous types in the WSDL.